# Assigning each field of an array to a variable, foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

I have a string array, and a for each loop.  I want to loop through the array and do something to each field and then output the result of each field to a new variable.

**EDIT:** Each field of the array gets a value from a hidden field that represents a time in mins.  In the foreach loop, it was my intention to convert each of the fields from mins to HH:mm format.  Then I need to pass the new format into a new variable.

**Array:**

```
string[] field = new string[8];
        field[0] = field_0_0.Value;
        field[1] = field_0_1.Value;
        field[2] = field_0_2.Value;
        field[3] = field_0_3.Value;
        field[4] = field_1_0.Value;
        field[5] = field_1_1.Value;
        field[6] = field_1_2.Value;
        field[7] = field_1_3.Value;
```

**Foreach Loop:**

```
foreach (string newfields in field)
{
    //Do something to each field  
}
```

The part I am looking for assistance with is assigning each result to a new variable.  Can anybody point me in the right direction, or even suggest a different/better way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the type of `field_0_0` and ...?

Comment: string,  it is getting the value from a hidden field.

Comment: So when you finish your loop you want to have the manipulated results available after the loop in separate variables? Can't you simply re-use your field array or does that need to retaint the original values?

Comment: @Chris_W `string` does not have any member called `Value`.

Comment: Is it the same thing for every field what are you doing in the foreach loop ... ?

Comment: @Chris_W: Your question is not clear. If field_0_0 till field_1_3 are hiidenfields and you want to store their values into an array, you have already the code.

Comment: Please see my edit, hope this makes the question clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an ordinary `for` loop.

```
for(int i=0;i<field.Length;i++) {
    string curValue = field[i];

    // do something with curValue, change it in some way

     field[i] = curValue; //update
}
```

If this is not what you're asking for, please clarify.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks very much!  Apologies if question was unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the object your are enumerating, but not with a foreach. You will need to use for loop. Modified sample thanks to comments

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
    mylist.Add("item1");
    mylist.Add("item2");

    for (int i = 0; i < mylist.Count; i++)
    {
        mylist[i] = mylist[i].Replace("i", "o");
    }
```

Comment: you can very well assign values to items inside a list using for/foreach..there is no need for two lists in this case.. its just that you can't remove/add items to the list you are enumerating currently.

Comment: Hmmmm why won't this work then:

`List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
        mylist.Add("item1");
        mylist.Add("item2");

        foreach (string item in mylist)
        {
            item = item.Replace("e", "o");
        }`

Answer (score 1):

Use `for` instead `foreach`, the `foreach` don't let you change your values.

Use a `for` like this one:

```
for(int i = 0; i < field.Length; i++)
   //Do something to each field 
   field[i] = "text"+i;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create variable counter and set it to zero.
2. `long i = 0;`
3. Create the for each loop.

```
foreach(string field in fields){
    // Use i counter to initialize the array index
    fields[i]="New Field String.";
    // Increment the counter i by 1
    i++;
}
```

4. This will assign a value to each of the fields array values